# Missing iris driver (iris_dri.so) and zink driver (zink_dri.so) for OpenGL (EGL)

Tags: drivers, plugins, amdgpu, ubuntu-studio, ardour

I am running Ubuntu Studio 22.04 on a Dell desktop.  I have an AMDGPU Radeon Pro WX7100 GPU.  I have recently run into a problem with a plugin for Ardour/Harrison Mixbus.  The graphics for the plugin do not work.  I've contacted Harrison/SSL, and was told that the issue was with OpenGL.  When I looked at OpenGL (EGL) I saw that the iris and zink drivers could not be found; as a result OpenGL (EGL) does not work.  When I installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04 on a virtual machine, the plugins worked fine.  On the VM, the OpenGL (EGL) driver was initialized and was working.

My question is: how do I install the iris and zink drivers?  I could not find them in the Ubuntu repositories.